# spring boot: 404 on login post call

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I know that there is many questions like this, but nothing I found helped me fix the issue.
I'm using Spring Boot with security to handle login, with custom login page. This is my config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CompetencyMatrixApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompetencyMatrixApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
    {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/matrix", "/matrix/show", "/cas/getImage", "/documentModal").access("hasRole('2')")
                .antMatchers("/matrix/fromFile", "/matrix/upload").access("hasRole('1')")
                .antMatchers("/cas/new", "/cas/uploadImage").access("hasRole('1')")
                .antMatchers("/department/**", "/departmentType/**").access("hasRole('1')")
                .antMatchers("/employee/**").access("hasRole('1')")
                .antMatchers("/position", "/position/**").access("hasRole('1')")
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/sign-in").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                .failureUrl("/sign-in?error")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/sign-in?logout")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
}
```

and login page (just the form part)

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
                <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" type='text' name='email' value=''
                               class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="password" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Hasło</label>
                        <input id="password" type='password' name='password'
                               class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">
                    </div>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Zaloguj"
                           class="shadow bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"/>
                </form>
```

So I get my custom page for login, but when I submit it I get 404 Whitelabel Error Page.
What am I missing here? Every example I saw was just using the default /login url to post login details and it worked, mine obviously doesn't even reach UserDetailsService

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, if someone comes here looking for solution, for me adding
`http.csrf().disable();` did the trick